# Creating a table with a column named ''PASSWORD"

Tags: mysql, passwords, create-table, identity-column, reserved

Here is my script and the error I am getting. What am I doing wrong?

```
create table PHONE_USERS (
 TELEPHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(80)  NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY 
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(80),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(80),
 KEYMAP_LASTNAME CHAR(4), 
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(80),
 CONSTRAINT LAST_NAME UNIQUE (TELEPNONE_NUMBER)
 );
```

> Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 31
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TELEPNONE_NUMBER": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Is that `TELEPNONE_NUMBER` or `TELEPHONE_NUMBER`

Comment: I do beleive that you have to show a little more info/code so that we could get a better picture and see where the problem resides. (We don't steal code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TELEPNONE_NUMBER` is misspelled. Is must be `TELEPHONE_NUMBER`

```
create table PHONE_USERS (
 TELEPHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(80)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(80),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(80),
 KEYMAP_LASTNAME CHAR(4), 
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(80),
 CONSTRAINT LAST_NAME UNIQUE (TELEPHONE_NUMBER)
 );
```

Comment: @Downvoter: please explaine the downvote!

Answer (score 1):

This error occured, because you are placing comma after `NOT NULL` and `TELEPHONE_NUMBER` spelling mismatch i think.

Change `TELEPNONE_NUMBER` to `TELEPHONE_NUMBER`

```
create table PHONE_USERS (
 TELEPHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(80)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(80),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(80),
 KEYMAP_LASTNAME CHAR(4), 
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(80),
 CONSTRAINT LAST_NAME UNIQUE (TELEPHONE_NUMBER)
 );
```